# collect takes more time than first for small dataset

Tags: java, apache-spark, hdfs

I have  data saved as a single partition on HDFS (in bytes) and when I want to get the content of the data using below code, `collect` takes more time than `first` in a single partition of the data.

```java
JavaRDD<String> mytext = sc.textFile("...");
List<String> lines = mytext.collect();
```

I was expecting `collect` and `first` to take the same time. Yet `collect` is slower than `first` for data in a single partition of HDFS.

What might be the reason behind this?

Comment: Why would retrieving the first record take the same time as retrieving all of the data?

Comment: since data is very small or tiny `collect` is taking almost 3 times than first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rdd.first()` doesnt have to scan the whole partition. It gets only the first 
item and returns it. 
`rdd.collect()` has to scan the whole partition, collect all of it and send 
all of it back (serialization + deserialization costs, etc.)

The [reason (see apache-spark-developers forum)](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/JavaRDD-collect-td324.html) is likely because first() is entirely executed on the driver 
node in the same process, while `collect`() needs to connect with worker 
nodes.

Usually the first time you run an action, most of the JVM code are not 
optimized, and the classloader also needs to load a lot of things on the 
fly. Having to connect with other processes via RPC can slow the first 
execution down in collect.

That said, if you run this a few times (in the same driver program) and it 
is still much slower, you should look into other factors such as network 
congestion, cpu/memory load on workers, etc.